# Error:no override found for 'vtkPolyDataMapper'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am trying to use PCL1.8.0 with vs2013 and running an example.
The problem is that when I run it, the window shows this message:

```
Generic Warning: In C:\Build\3rdParty\x64\VTK-7.0.0\Rendering\Core\vtkPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 28
Error: no override found for 'vtkPolyDataMapper'.
```

I had done try to add this:

```
#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 4(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL,vtkRenderingOpenGL)
#define vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT 1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL)
```

or this:

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2);
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

Both occurred other problems. I don't use cmake.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem without cmake?

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code:

```
    #include <vtkAutoInit.h>
    VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL);
    VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

and add "opengl32.lib" to Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies

Hope this help!